# NVDA screen reader ignores time element

Tags: html, time, accessibility, screen-readers, nvda

In a calendar I use abbreviated date/time formats. To make it screenreader-friendly I use the time element, as recommended in a lot of articles and posts. But somehow NVDA just ignores it.

For example, it reads "Fr. 13." no matter if I use the datetime attribute or not. And it always reads it wrong (13 franc, meaning Swiss franc).

```
<time datetime="2023-02-13T00:00:00+0100">
        Fr. 13. 00:00 Uhr
</time>
```

Besides ISO Date I tried using different datetime formats. Makes no difference.

I know that there are workarounds. Using aria labels for example. But if possible I want it to work that way, because as far as I know it should and aria is to be avoided whenever possible.

Comment: What does NVDA mean?

Comment: It's a screen reader. I edited the heading to make that more clear.

Comment: Why is the attribute not in a recognised ISO format like `2023-02-13T00:00:00+0100` and why is the date string not in a recognised INTL format? I see it is in a  DIN 1355 format, but perhaps use a newer one or one that IS recognised by a non-german screen reader

Comment: I didn't try any other screenreaders so far besides NVDA and the built-in windows thing. I don't have JAWS.

Comment: use js `new Date(str).toISOString()` to get a valid format.

Comment: No datetime here: https://www.powermapper.com/tests/screen-readers/attributes/

Comment: Alternatively try `<time datetime="2023-02-13T00:00:00+0100" aria-label="Freitag, der Dreizehnte, um Mitternacht">
        Fr. 13. 00:00 Uhr
</time>`

Comment: I will try it again with the correct iso date (got that wrong). But the point is : In theory it should work with the time element alone. Datetime attribute isn't mandatory. What's interesting is, it isn't even listed here: https://www.powermapper.com/tests/screen-readers/elements/ Which means probably it isn't supported at all. A definitive answer if it should work or not would be nice. For the moment I have to stick with aria labels I guess. Which is a shame because they are not language independent.

Comment: Continue using the `<time>` element.  The [first step in accessibility is using semantically correct HTML elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/aria-in-html/#rule1), whether or not that element is currently supported by screen readers. So keep doing what you're doing and also follow @quentinc's advice in his answer.

Comment: For the sake of completeness: I tried it with the correct ISO date now. Of course that didn't work either. I'll edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the major screen readers specially handle `<time>` currently, as far as I know.

However, you should't be afraid about your text being not spoken exactly as you wish, and you shouldn't try to add a special label if it's just to enhance the pronunciation to your own liking.

- Interpretation of dates, numbers, etc. and how they are spoken differ between screen readers and voices used. By adding a label to fix the pronunciation, you may help for one particular configuration, but do more harm than good for all other.
- What you think should be spoken is maybe not what a VI user would like to be spoken in the same situation; the best is to make a real test with VI people to find out if it's a real problem or not.
- As VI users, we are used to pronounciation issues, and we aren't stupid; we can most of the time still understand what you really mean anyway
- Screen readers include pronunciation dictionaries allowing to customize what we don't like

Comment: To add to what @quentinc said, another drawback about trying to use an `aria-label` (which probably wouldn't be announced since it's not on an [interactive element](https://www.w3.org/TR/using-aria/#label-support)) to force a certain pronunciation is that the `aria-label` would be exposed to Braille users so if you try to spell something phonetically, it's going to feel/read incorrectly in Braille.

Comment: Of course you can understand what is meant, but I would imagine that it's annoying anyway. It shure annoys me. But I understand the point, especially considering the braille problem. I will stick to the time element without the label. Hopefully support for it will improve in the future.

Comment: For your specific case, it isn't at all standard that "Fr. 13" is interpreted as "13 francs". This is part of the internal translations made by the particular synthesizer you are using. It's annoying, but rather usual. The best you can do is trying to play with different punctuations/spacing.  . I have myself the same problem where "F1" is said as "1 franc" in some cases. The bug exists since more than 20 years and it has never been fixed.