Screen reader narrating 00:00:00 as 'midnight' when it should be narrated as 0hrs:0mins:0seconds
I am trying to design accessible React application by utilizing aria labels. I am relatively new to aria, and I can't find a lot of supporting documentation on the nitty-gritty of implementations.
I have a configurable delay field in my application. If the user has not configured a delay, it will default to 00:00:00. Currently this is narrating using a screen reader as "midnight", but I need it to narrate as zero hours, zero minutes, and zero seconds. Or, "no delay configured". I can't seem to override this default behavior, though.
Of note, if any values are updated from the default, it narrates exactly as it should (00:09:00 reads as "nine minutes"), even without any aria attributes.
Here is my component, including my addition of an aria-label (not working)
<div>
    <MaskedTextField
        mask="dh:ms:ms"
        className="name"
        maskFormat={maskFormat}
        value={this.delay} //defaults to 00:00:00
        onChange={this.setDelay}
        aria-labelledby={this.delay === "00:00:00" ? "no delay configured" : this.delay}
    />
</div>

I've tried aria-label, aria-labelledby, and even aria-hiding my input field and trying to sneak in a hidden span with this information. Nothing works, it still narrates as "midnight". How can I fix it to say its actual value, and why is it saying midnight?
Edit:
MaskedTextField renders a simple text box with a default input of 00:00:00. These fields are editable, but only if it matches the rules created in the mask.
image of the component

I think you meant to use aria-label= not aria-labelledby= since you're passing the actual label and not a reference to an element.

Thanks for the quick response. I'm still learning the difference between the two, but I've tried both with no luck.
Edit: I thought I understood that you should use aria-labelledby for labels that are text or otherwise readable? And aria-label for things you could only understood if you saw, like icons, buttons with symbols, etc?

What does <MaskedTextField> actually render in terms of HTML?

<div class="TextField-fieldGroup fieldGroup-1174"><input type="text" id="TextField235" class="TextField-field field-1175" aria-invalid="false" value="00:00:00"></div>

aria-labelledby is a reference to another element that contains the actual label. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-labelledby.

I don't want to repeat myself once more. The following answers should help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77579072/accessible-values-000-as-a-duration-not-a-time-1-12-2023-as-a-date-etc/77581644#77581644 ,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74021046/getting-voiceover-to-read-distance-and-time-correctly/74022990#74022990
and
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75322134/nvda-screen-reader-ignores-time-element/75325755#75325755
